# CodeIgniter query error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am using codeIgniter and am really stucked on it.

Here's my model function

```
public function get_products_names($c_name)
{

$this->db->query('SELECT name
                  FROM products
                  WHERE category=$c_name');

return $query->result_array();
}
```

And I'm calling this function from the controller class as follows

```
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data['products_categories'] = $this->products_model->get_products_names('Aata');
    echo $data['products_categories']['name'];
```

And its giving me the following error, I don't know why

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$c_name' in 'where clause'

SELECT name FROM products WHERE category=$c_name

Filename: C:\wamp\www\OSW_appnsys\misystemsys\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: escape `"SELECT name
                  FROM products
                  WHERE category=".$c_name`

Comment: giving error `Unknown column 'Aata' in 'where clause'

SELECT name FROM products WHERE category=Aata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i may be deviating a little , but why dont you try something like this :
(Use active records makes the query more "readable")
Model:

```
public function get_products_names($c_name)
{
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->where('category',$c_name);
$query = $this->db->get('products');
if($query->num_rows) 
return $query->result();
return false;
}
```

controller :

```
$names_arr = array();
$this->load->model('products_model');
$result = $this->products_model->get_products_names('Aata');
foreach($result as $r){
array_push($names_arr,$r->name)
}
print_r($names_arr);
```

Comment: hmm make sure your column name exactly matches, or first if there is a column called category in your db table 'product'

Comment: are you using mysql, if so , have you tried running the query in the mysql prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the single quotes to double. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.

```
public function get_products_names($c_name)
{

$this->db->query("SELECT name
                  FROM products
                  WHERE category=$c_name");

return $query->result_array();
}
```

not sure if this is safe way about it however.

Comment: now its giving me the error `Unknown column 'Aata' in 'where clause'

SELECT name FROM products WHERE category=Aata` however Aata is a category

Answer (score 0):

You can give as:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT name
              FROM products
              WHERE category='.$c_name);
return $query->result(); / return $query->row_array();
```

it will works fine.